# Why Grails is using H2 instead of Oracle?

Tags: oracle, grails, controller, h2

I have spent a lot of time to resolve this problem. I'm begginer in GRAILS and GROOVY.
I have legacy oracle database schema named "tms_dev". This schema has some tables (for example checktypes table). Also I have domain class Checktype and ChecktypesController class - controller generated by GRAILS.

This class has list method:

def list(Integer max) {

```
params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
[checktypesInstanceList: Checktypes.list(params), checktypesInstanceTotal: Checktypes.count()]
```

}

Also I configured Datasource.groovy file to work with oracle with such contents

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
    username = "TMS_DEV"
    password = "password"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@server_name:1522:sid_name"
        }
    }
production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@server_name:1522:sid_name"
        }
    }
```

I run my application. And click "tst7.ChecktypesController" refence on the main page.

As a result I have exception:

```
| Error 2012-08-27 14:41:03,469 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Table "CHECKTYPES" not found; SQL statement:
select * from ( select this_.CHECKTYPECODE as CHECKTYP1_21_0_, this_.active as active21_0_, this_.availabilitychecktype as availabi3_21_0_, this_.checktypecode as checktyp1_21_0_, this_.checktypedescr as checktyp4_21_0_, this_.TARGETTYPECODE as TARGETTY5_21_0_ from CHECKTYPES this_ ) where rownum <= ? [42102-164]
| Error 2012-08-27 14:41:03,547 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - JdbcSQLException occurred when processing request: [GET] /Tst7/checktypes/list
Table "CHECKTYPES" not found; SQL statement:
select * from ( select this_.CHECKTYPECODE as CHECKTYP1_21_0_, this_.active as active21_0_, this_.availabilitychecktype as availabi3_21_0_, this_.checktypecode as checktyp1_21_0_, this_.checktypedescr as checktyp4_21_0_, this_.TARGETTYPECODE as TARGETTY5_21_0_ from CHECKTYPES this_ ) where rownum <= ? [42102-164]. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Table "CHECKTYPES" not found; SQL statement:
select * from ( select this_.CHECKTYPECODE as CHECKTYP1_21_0_, this_.active as active21_0_, this_.availabilitychecktype as availabi3_21_0_, this_.checktypecode as checktyp1_21_0_, this_.checktypedescr as checktyp4_21_0_, this_.TARGETTYPECODE as TARGETTY5_21_0_ from CHECKTYPES this_ ) where rownum <= ? [42102-164]
    Line | Method
->>  329 | getJdbcSQLException       in org.h2.message.DbException
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    169 | get                       in     ''
|    146 | get . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   4753 | readTableOrView           in org.h2.command.Parser
|   1080 | readTableFilter . . . . . in     ''
|   1686 | parseSelectSimpleFromPart in     ''
|   1793 | parseSelectSimple . . . . in     ''
|   1680 | parseSelectSub            in     ''
|   1523 | parseSelectUnion . . . .  in     ''
|   1022 | readTableFilter           in     ''
|   1686 | parseSelectSimpleFromPart in     ''
|   1793 | parseSelectSimple         in     ''
|   1680 | parseSelectSub . . . . .  in     ''
|   1523 | parseSelectUnion          in     ''
|   1511 | parseSelect . . . . . . . in     ''
|    405 | parsePrepared             in     ''
|    279 | parse . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    251 | parse                     in     ''
|    217 | prepareCommand . . . . .  in     ''
|    415 | prepareLocal              in org.h2.engine.Session
|    364 | prepareCommand . . . . .  in     ''
|   1121 | prepareCommand            in org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection
|     71 | <init> . . . . . . . . .  in org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement
|    267 | prepareStatement          in org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection
|    281 | prepareStatement . . . .  in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection
|    313 | prepareStatement          in org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
|     55 | <init> . . . . . . . . .  in grails.orm.PagedResultList
|     45 | list                      in tst7.ChecktypesController
|    195 | doFilter . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter                  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1110 | runWorker . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Then I tried to create direct Oracle connection in list method

```
def list(Integer max) {

        def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@server_name:1522:instance_name", "TMS_DEV",
            "password", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
        sql.eachRow("select * from Dbdrivers"){
            println it.dbdrivercode
        }
}
```

Than I run application. As result println it.dbdrivercode - works fine (CONNECTION WORKS!!!).

Most strange in this problem is that exception is generated by h2 (H2 in memory database) class (org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection
,org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection
 and so on).

Comment: To get rid of the easy stuff... does the table CHECKTYPES actually exist in the schema TMS_DEV?

Comment: Yes of course! this table exists in schema TMS_DEV. More over when I try to map this table in domain class like "class Checktypes {
    static mapping = {
         table 'TMS_DEV.CHECKTYPES' ... " instead of  "table 'CHECKTYPES" ... I have error "schema TMS_DEV not found"...

Comment: It seems that the driver used is `org.h2` and not the Oracle driver like you said. Your `Datasource.groovy` have just what you posted? Your Config.groovy not override some database config? What's the Grails version?

Comment: --Your Datasource.groovy have just what you posted?
YES
--Your Config.groovy not override some database config? 
NOT OVERRIDE
--What's the Grails version? 
GRAILS VERSION - 2.1.0

Comment: Yes, for some reason it is using the H2 database and not Oracle. You could set a breakpoint on the one of the H2 classes to find out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defaulting to the H2 driver because your *production* and *development* blocks are being ignored when outside an *environments* block.

Comment: In that case would you please mark my answer as 'accepted'. Good to hear that your problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like application cache issue. try running grails clean before running the app.